# How to create a candidate key alias in the select query from a view?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a view already in the snowflake which consisit of following columns

```
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4
```

i need to create a unique key with combination of below keys as alias, so that it would not actually create a unique key in the view

```
col1,
col2,
col3,
```

so somthing like

```
select unique(col1,col2,col3) as uniq_id from my view
```

i actually do want to store the 'uniq_id' in view.
Is this possible in snowflake?

Comment: For unique you need to use distinct. So something like select distinct concat(col1,col2,col3) as uniq_id from myview. You need to include more details and some sample data, showing expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hash or md5 function in Snowflake.
Refer here : https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009MGCEJSA5/can-the-hash-function-be-used-to-create-a-distinct-unique-id-for-each-row-in-snowflake-table